# how to undu split vertical in kate?

Tags: kate

is there a keyboard shortcut?  (split vertical is ctrl-shift-L) -http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=veuviqxg4q2xtqi4&number=2

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it.  shift-ctrl-R in a given view closes it.